# How to handle API differences when developing a data driven renderer?

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, renderer, data-driven

I'm working on a real-time renderer engine for a game (https://github.com/ghostec/White). I was implementing it using an OOP approach. However, after reading about data-driven programming, I'm tempted to rewrite my code using this paradigm.

I was using virtuals (abstract factories) to be API agnostic (directx vs opengl).

Since DDP is mainly about data. How can I design for example my Model class (if you look at my code, there are Model, ModelOpenGL, ModelFactory and ModelFactoryOpenGL classes) to work with both directx and opengl?

OpenGL and DirectX have different data elements and I suppose that even with analogous data types, they can handle them differently. How this will reflect in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I got an awesome answer on /r/gamedev

Check it out: http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/22e81o/how_to_handle_api_differences_when_developing_a/